# Can I shorten my directory commands in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I shorten my directory commands in ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/299872/can-i-shorten-my-directory-commands-in-ubuntu)

When working on a rails app I like to open all of my files through the command line like so

```
cd my_app
gedit app/views/user/show.html.erb
```

Is there a way that I could shorten this so that I could just write something like

```
gedit  user_views/show.html.erb
```

?

I would like the console to stay in the main directory, I just don't like having to type out app/controller/user_controler.rb every time I want to open the user controller. I know that I could just open the file with my mouse, but I feel like moving from keyboard to mouse breaks my focus a little bit. When I can just tap away at the keyboard it seems like I have a more smooth workflow.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

`gedit my`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`vi`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`u`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`sh`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`ht`<kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

or such depending on how well your folders are named.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider defining a simple shell variable:

```
cd my_app
VIEWS=app/viwes/user
gedit $VIEWS/show.html.erb
gedit $VIEWS/xy.html.erb
```

Chose a shorter variable if you're a really lazy guy.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a command like 'gedit_userviews' and add some bash auto completion.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a link to the target directory

```
ln /home/yourname/app/views/user/ sname
```

then you could use

```
gedit sname/show.html.erb
```